# How can I make payments flow directly through my website, which acts as a proxy, to the actual seller?

Tags: javascript, forms, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I have started creating a website which allows users to search through various digital products and buy them. This is all going according to plan, but I've hit a problem as far as payment is concerned.

The idea is, if a user buys something on the website, it appears to them that they have bought it from us, but it appears to the seller that it has been bought from their website. Ultimately, this just means that my site acts like a proxy for the transaction, as the transaction is between the buyer and the seller, and no money should ever be in my own possession. However, I'm unsure of how to do this.

The simplest way to do this, is using PayPal, since the user would click 'buy now with PayPal, and could be redirected to the usual PayPal screen that the sellers website would normally redirect to.

The issue with that is that not all sellers use PayPay - some only accept card payment. I'm guessing that the two options in this case would be

1. Somehow copy the card payment form inputs from the sellers website to mine, so that the details are actually being (indirectly) typed into the sellers website.
2. Create my own secure payment form so that the details are given to us and then (securely) passed on to the seller of the resource.

May I reiterate that the seller should not be able to tell that the sale has come through my website, and the buyer should be given the illusion nthat they are buying the resource from the website.

What is the easiest and most secure way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand from your question is that you are essentially trying to make an aggregator website .

Of the top of my mind there are two ways you could try to solve this.

1. Check if these sellers have an active affiliate program. This will be the easier way out.
2. Try and create an iframe around the payment process that the seller has . Mind you this is just a possibility , I am not sure this will work. But this involves more work because one solution may not work for all the sellers.